# Razor: calling Javascript from C# or other way around

Tags: javascript, razor, viewmodel

In my view I have a JavaScript method which I'd like to call passing in data from my model.

Here's my code

```
@for(var i = 0; i < @Model.SearchCriteria.Locations.Count; i++) {
                        locationLog(@Model.SearchCriteria.Locations[i]);
                }
```

The JavaScript method is locationLog.  Naturally, this is throwing an error saying that this method is not recognised.  What must I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried wrapping your call to "locationLog" in a script tag?

```
@for(var i = 0; i < @Model.SearchCriteria.Locations.Count; i++) {
    <script type="text/javascript">locationLog(@Model.SearchCriteria.Locations[i]);</script>
}
```